# Contact that cant be made a favourite

Tags: contacts

In my contacts on my Samsung phone I have a contact that I cant "star", other contacts have that star you can click on to make them a favourite but this one contact that just isn't there. I've tried creating a new contact but it just won't let me make her  a favourite.

Any idea why?
Thanks.

Edit:because I can't add comments.  Its a Samsung S10e OS ver G970FXXU9DTJA
[image]

Comment: Hello. Which Android version and Samsung device are you using? Can you post (in a manner hiding the identity of your contact) the details that you have added into this contact?

Comment: Hello @CletusVanDamme. It seems that you have lost access to your account with username Tim. You can get your current account merged with that one and get ownership of this question. Please use the [contact](https://android.stackexchange.com/contact) form to have this sorted out for you. Good luck.